# Wix: Copy log file

Tags: wix, copy, logging

Is there a way to copy msi log file in scope of installation procces (after InstallFinalize)?
This file is locked by installer procces until installation end and xcopy or similar CAs don't  work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by using Scripting.FileSystemObject from Microsoft Scripting Runtime.